# Check if pdf file exists on given url in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, pdf, cors

Is there any solution in javascript which can be used to determine if pdf file exists on a given external url?
`object` tag supports onerror event only in firefox but not in chrome/safari/edge.

I've tried with attaching `href` to `link` tag but that won't work if test from `https` to `http`

The idea is to display pdf in object tag if url is valid (file exists), otherwise a custom error should be displayed

PS Ajax call doesn't work because of cors

**EDIT**

```
<object onerror="alert('error')" id="myPdf" type="application/pdf" data="https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3285X.pdf">
    Unable to open the PDF file.
</object>
```

`onerror` will be triggered in Firefox but not in Chrome

Comment: The onerror event works, show us some code. Most likely you have a syntax error.

Comment: Ajax will work if you make the call through a CORS proxy. You can either set up your own proxy, or you can use a public CORS proxy — just by prefixing your current request URL with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`. For code samples and a longer explanation, see the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141. That’ll also work for a test for an `http` resource.

Comment: @Scriptonomy I've added an example which works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Comment: @sideshowbarker `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` is sometimes down so it's not reliable

Comment: @ilijaveselica it’s a pretty trivial to set up a similar CORS proxy instance of your own — using the code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ or such, or else just rolling your own in whatever your preferred server-side programming runtime is

Comment: that is a potential workaround but it sounds like a very clumsy solution to have another server running just for that purpose